# Oracle database query: 'WHERE' working not as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

Good afternoon!

I started recently to work with Oracle database. In my query to the database I see very strange behaviour of 'WHERE' clause.

I have 2 tables, `client_status_history` and `status_sdim`. `client_status_history` contains history of status for each client and looks like:

| date | client_id | client_status_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2020 | 123456 | 1 |
| 01.02.2020 | 123457 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

`status_sdim` is a dictionary for status names that looks like:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'NEW' |
| 2 | 'ACTIVE' |
| 3 | 'INACTIVE' |
| ... | ... |

`id` of status is VARCHAR(2). For status values 1 and 2 I want to know how many people had such a status at the end of each month in client_status_history` table. My select statement:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(h.date) mnth, 
       h.client_status_id status, -- just to check
       d.name status_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) n_clients
FROM client_status_history h
LEFT JOIN status_sdim d on d.id = h.client_status_id
-- get only end-of-month values
WHERE date = LAST_DAY(date)
AND client_status_id IN ('1', '2') 
GROUP BY LAST_DAY(h.date), 
       h.client_status_id, -- just to check
       d.name
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

I was very surprised when in the resulting table I saw not only status 1 and 2, but 3 etc. despite the fact that I have filtered out status codes other than 1 and 2 in WHERE clause.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample dat in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2?

Comment: This query cannot return rows with client_status_id other than 1 and 2. Your real query must look different.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is when you're doing the JOIN of a VARCHAR2 to a number.

In addition, you are using 'date', which is a reserved word. In my test CASE below I created the ID columns of both tables as numbers and changed the 'date' to cdate and everything appears to work fine.

In the future, to help others help you, there should be sample data that is indicative of your test CASE. For example, there should have been some rows that contain the last day of the month.

```
CREATE TABLE client_status_history
 (cdate, client_id, client_status_id) AS
SELECT  DATE '2022-01-31', 1,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-02-28', 1,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-03-31', 1,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-01-31', 2,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-02-28', 2,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-03-31', 2,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-04-30', 2,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-01-31', 3,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-02-28', 3,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-03-31', 3,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-04-30', 3,2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  DATE '2022-05-31', 3,3 FROM DUAL;


CREATE TABLE status_sdim (id, name) AS
SELECT 1,    'NEW' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,    'ACTIVE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,    'INACTIVE' FROM DUAL;

SELECT LAST_DAY(h.cdate) mnth, 
       h.client_status_id status, -- just to check
       d.name status_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT client_id) n_clients
FROM client_status_history h
LEFT JOIN status_sdim d on d.id = h.client_status_id
-- get only end-of-month values
WHERE cdate = LAST_DAY(cdate)
AND client_status_id IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY LAST_DAY(h.cdate), 
       h.client_status_id, -- just to check
       d.name
ORDER BY 1, 2;

MNTH    STATUS  STATUS_NAME N_CLIENTS
31-JAN-22   1   NEW 3
28-FEB-22   1   NEW 1
28-FEB-22   2   ACTIVE  2
31-MAR-22   2   ACTIVE  1
30-APR-22   2   ACTIVE  1
```